# Error While Starting the Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat

I deployed the war file in Tomcat/webapps folder. Then I start my tomcat server using the comment catalina.bat start. It shows the following error,

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Feb 25, 2015 10:14:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.net.URLConnection.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:967)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Feb 25, 2015 10:14:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.net.HttpURLConnection.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:967)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Feb 25, 2015 10:14:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNotationDecl.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.DTDGrammar.notationDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDProcessor.notationDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanNotationDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:967)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Feb 25, 2015 10:14:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory examples
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/impl/dtd/XMLNotationDecl
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.DTDGrammar.notationDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDProcessor.notationDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanNotationDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:967)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNotationDecl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    ... 49 more
```

Any idea about fixing this issue. Please help me

Thanks in advance
Vishwa

Comment: why don't you use startup.bat or startup.sh to run Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Call `RUN` utility, enter: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`
[image]
Choose `Environment Variable`
[image]
In section System variables, set variables, for example:

`CATALINA_HOME = C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.18`

`Path` add to the end: `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin`
[image]

Then, try restart your computer and Tomcat instance.

Comment: I am using two tomcats in different ports.. for the first tomcat I set the path name as TOMCAT_HOME(C:\softwares\apache-tomcat-ho\apache-tomcat-7.0.11),  for the second tomcat I set the path name as HO_TOMCAT_HOME(C:\softwares\apache-tomcat-bo\apache-tomcat-7.0.11). But it is not working.

Comment: We use `CATALINA_HOME` is offical setting, not `TOMCAT_HOME`. Check read/write permission at this directory: `C:\software\...`. Remove 2 instances, delete all old directory and file.  You will reinstall only 1 Tomcat instance later is better. Because 1 Tomcat instance maybe install many web applications inside it. Try new Tomcat version if you don't have any limit.

Comment: at the same time I need to run two different applications in two different ports, if I use one tomcat instance only one connection port will be there, how I will run two applications in same port?

Comment: Offical instruction for you:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Multiple_Instances
and 
http://www.ansoncheunghk.info/article/5-steps-install-multiple-apache-tomcat-instance-windows

Comment: Thank you. I am started to setup.

Comment: I created two tomcat instance and tried to run both the tomcats, The application that is installed in first tomcat runs properly, but the second tomcat shows the same error. Any idea

Comment: My computer have been install many Java application servers. I don't install more, you let try to install yourselft.